# sailsjs update view while controller is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express, sails.js

Firstly I'm totally new to SailsJs. I've been asked to learn it and make some demo app. One of them is simply a loop in a controller and output each results in the view while the controller is still working.
However it doesn't seem simple as that. After some research I found the async lib but I can't use it since we're using an older version of node and dependencies doesn't met and I can't use any other node version for some reason. So is there any way to do this without using any other lib? Maybe I should use sockets for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask why you think you need the async library for this? I have written out a test controller below. In order to do what you want to do, you just have to use the express methods required and not use the custom responses that sails.js has built in.

```
TestController.js
module.exports.test = function(req,res,next){

 response.status(200).set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');;

 for(var i = 0; i < 10, i++){

 response.write(i);

 }
 return response.end();

};
```

Comment: i guess you mean `module.exports.test = ...`

Comment: Sorry I'm a big beginner at sails and nodejs. Indeed async was useless. I though I would use it because the aim os to send res.write result to the view. However I don't see how that would be possible without using sockets?
So let's say you add a wait for 5 seconds in your for. I would want to update the view everytime the loop produces a new response

Comment: What does not work about the example I put forth above?

Comment: @Meeker, your example only send the result to the user at return.
What they want is to print on screen very time the cicle is iterated (dynamically)
As it's arquitected, I might suspect that is not possible. Does anyone knows a way?

Comment: I have not looked at this answer since I wrote it, but yes, it appears he wants to stream the results. There are means, but it depends on the use case. Do we mean to dump HTML in chunks, or are we dealing with continuously changing data that we want to up the client with? Based on his mention of sockets, I suspect its the later. In which, yes he would want sockets. Sails has wonderfull sockets implementation.